# Disable the highlighted date in UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker, uipicker

Is it possible to completely disable the highlighted date in the UIDatePicker.Dont want to show the blue color for any dates

Answer (score 0):

I think it is default behavior of UIDatePicker. So it is not possible. So better option is

that you can use a customize Date picker.